# Scanner input not working (Java)?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java and have been trying to create an interactive game. I could make it in one class however I just recently learned how to use two classes so I wanted to try it out. Anyway, it seems my Scanner in my second class(tuna) is not working for some reason. I have tried to make it with if and if else statements but that didn't work either(and yes I was using'.equals' not '==' for the parameters of the if statements). I am legitimately stuck and need help. I have looked for answers on Stack but have failed to find any for this problem. Please tell me what is wrong with this part of the code as it is probably a logic error. If this is a duplicate send me the link to the answer and I will take this one down.
CODE: 
FIRST CLASS:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class hand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tuna opObject = new tuna();
        //creating input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //instructions
        System.out.println("This is an interactive game. You are a traveler and have come across this strange hotel. Type in 'go' to begin.");
        // Initializing game
        if(input.nextLine().equals ("go")) {
                System.out.println("A smiling, some what tall fellow in a red suit walks up to you.'Welcome to the amazing, KingstonTraveler Hotel! How may I serve you traveler?'");
            }
        System.out.println("Will you a) punch him b) 'I would like a room' c) DIE! ");
        opObject.options();
        }
    }
```

SECOND CLASS(scanner not working) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tuna {
    Scanner input = new Scanner("System.in");
    public String answer = input.nextLine();
    public void options() {
        switch(answer){
        case "a": System.out.println("answer a");
            break;
        case "b": System.out.println("answer b");
            break;
        case "c": System.out.println("answer c");
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Compare `new Scanner(System.in)` vs. `new Scanner("System.in")`

Comment: forggot to mention the problem was I couldn't input anything after the options a,b and c

Comment: You should start the names of your classes with an uppercase letter. Just a convention in Java.

Comment: Also don't forget to close stuff when you have finished using it :)

Comment: Why is the topic set on hold because it "cannot be reproduced"? The problem is very well reproduceable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the tuna class:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("System.in");
```

This creates a [Scanner, that scans only on the String "System.in"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-). If you remove the `"`, you will notice, that you have to input something before your program starts. This is because attributes (in this case `input`) are defined, when the corresponding object gets created (i.e. 1st line in `main` method). What you want is something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tuna { // Classes should always begin with an uppercase letter

    // Moved object attributes into method
    public void options() {
        // Now input is read if options() gets called
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        switch(answer) {
        case "a":
            System.out.println("answer a");
            break;
        case "b":
            System.out.println("answer b");
            break;
        case "c":
            System.out.println("answer c");
        }
        input.close(); // Close stream when we are done
    }
}
```